# Move the data from different rows with same ID in same rows but different column in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, rownum

I have a data like

```
  ID   ded1   ded2   ded3   ded4 
  ------------------------------
  1    2
  1    3
  1    4
```

I want:

```
ID   ded1   ded2   ded3   ded4
------------------------------
1    2      3      4
```

`ded4` is blank since there is 3 values, if 4th value was there then `ded4` fills up

Comment: Before we answer: What happens if you have, say, 30 rows? What do you want to see then?

Comment: What platform are you using?

Comment: data goes from ded1 to ded30, but my table in SQL has just ded6 as limit so we need to account for max 6 rows.

Comment: Here is a hint, you can give each row a number like this `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID) as rn` in a select statement.

Comment: SSMS - SQL server management studio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While @ConsiderMe answer is quite correct, you can also do 4 joins if you have issues with the group by or there are additional columns you want to include from the source table.  This is sometime the only viable solution.  (BTW a pivot it basically the same as this code).

This code is slight slower than @CondiderMe's answer since it requires 3 scans/seeks and his is only 2.  So only use this if you need to.

```
With addRN AS
(
  SELECT *,
        row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY ded1) AS rn
  FROM tbl
)
SELECT ids.id, r1.ded1 as ded1, r2.ded1 as ded2, r3.ded1 ad ded3, r4.ded1 as ded4
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT id FROM tbl) ids
LEFT JOIN addRN r1 ON ids.id = r1.id AND rn = 1
LEFT JOIN addRN r2 ON ids.id = r2.id AND rn = 2
LEFT JOIN addRN r3 ON ids.id = r3.id AND rn = 3
LEFT JOIN addRN r3 ON ids.id = r3.id AND rn = 4
```

Answer (score 2):

**If and only if** you have a limited number of columns and you feel like you don't need a function that assigns your values to a column named dynamically, then you could do this the following way:

Use an analytic function like `row_number()` to determine the order - which value should go under which column, then group your result by `id` and take `max()` value to make one row out of your `CASE` statements.

```
SELECT
  id,
  MAX(CASE WHEN ded_rn = 1 THEN ded1 END) AS ded1,
  MAX(CASE WHEN ded_rn = 2 THEN ded1 END) AS ded2,
  MAX(CASE WHEN ded_rn = 3 THEN ded1 END) AS ded3,
  MAX(CASE WHEN ded_rn = 4 THEN ded1 END) AS ded4
FROM(
  SELECT
    *,
    row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY ded1) AS ded_rn
  FROM 
    tbl
   ) foo
GROUP BY id
```

Here's an [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/547705/6) presenting discussed case with sample data.